# Mock aggregator's message store

Tags: spring-integration

We want to mock the Aggregators message store for some tests but we cannot find how to inject it into a JUnit test. We tried using the AggregatingMessageHandler without success. Is there a way to do it?

thanks in advance

Regards

Guzman

EDIT:

```
@Autowire
private MessageHandler aggregator;

@Test
public test(){
  SimpleMessageStore store = new SimpleMessageStore(50) {
    @Override
    public MessageGroup addMessageToGroup(Object groupId, Message<?> message) {
      if (simulateConnectionException) {
        throw new SomeException("Foo");
      }
      return super.addMessageToGroup(groupId, message);
    }
  aggregator.setMessageStore(store);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to mock it? The `SimpleMessageStore` is a basic, in-memory, implementation that you can manipulate as-needed for your test cases.

That said, you should have no problems mocking the `MessageGroupStore` and provide it to the aggregator (either through the XML namespace, or directly).

However, you would have to examine the aggregator (and `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler`) to determine exactly what methods to mock, and when they are invoked.

Hence my statement about it being easier to just use an injected `SimpleMessageStore`; that's what most of the framework tests do - see `AggregatorTests`.

EDIT:

(See comment).

I suggest you do something like this...

```
private final SimpleMessageStore store = new SimpleMessageStore(50) {

    @Override
    public MessageGroup addMessageToGroup(Object groupId, Message<?> message) {
        if (simulateConnectionException) {
            throw new SomeException("Foo");
        }
        return super.addMessageToGroup(groupId, message);
    }

};
```

Comment: we don't have to lose messages all along the flow, so we want to simulate a connection between the aggregator and it's message store. At some random point of the aggregator we want to throw a ConnectionException. I look foward the AggregtorTests

Comment: Gary, I tried your suggestion but could only inject in my JUnit an EventDrivenConsumer, where I cannot set the CustomMessageStore. I need the MessageHandler to do so. I could use a test flow an define a custom aggregator to inject it to my test but I this would not test the real flow. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Add `@Qualifier("aggId.handler")` to the `@Autowired`. Where `aggId` is the `id` of the aggregator.